# Tecnica de programacion Greedy Contar cantidad de monedas

Tags: java

Cuento con una dificultad, no estoy pudiendo realizar el listado de monedas utilizadas con el cual llego a la suma a pagar.

**Esto es lo que solicitan hacer:**

Escriba un algoritmo que permita el ingreso de un número entero de monedas, donde (1 < n <=10) y luego solicite los valores de dichas monedas. Finalmente, el programa debe solicitar un
monto decimal a pagar. El algoritmo debe mostrar el listado de las monedas usadas para pagar
el monto usando siempre en primer lugar las monedas de mayor denominación.

**Este es el codigo que tengo realizado, que actualmente me suma todos los valores**

```
package tecDeProg.Rercursividad.tecGreedy;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjercicioUno {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int cantidadMonedas = 0;


    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de monedas");

    cantidadMonedas = sc.nextInt();

    double monedas[] = new double[cantidadMonedas];

    for (int i = 0; i < monedas.length; i++) {
        int mayor = 0;
        System.out.print("Ingresar el Valor de la moneda " + (i + 1) + " ° ");
        monedas[i] = sc.nextInt();


    }
    for (int i = 0; i < monedas.length; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < monedas.length; j++) {

            double aux = 0;

            if (monedas[i] < monedas[j]) {
                aux = monedas[i];
                monedas[i] = monedas[j];
                monedas[j] = aux;

            }

        }
    }

    double apagar = 0;
    double monedasUsadas[] = new double[10];

    System.out.println("Ingrese el monto a abonar");
    apagar = sc.nextDouble();

    for (int i = 0; i < monedas.length; i++) {


        double pago = 0;
        if (pago < apagar) {
            pago = pago + monedas[i];
            monedasUsadas[i] = monedas[i];
        } else {
            pago = pago - monedas[i];
            monedasUsadas[i] = 0;
        }

    }



}


}
```

Comment: En el último `if (pago < apagar) {` pon un `System.out.println` con la moneda que has utilizado. No necesitas más no? O imprimir el array `monedasUsadas[i]`.

Comment: Por favor, tómate el trabajo para depurar **tu** programa. Sigue el funcionamiento del mismo, consulta el estado interno (depurador o `println`) y mira si lo que ves se corresponde con lo esperador. Si cuando encuentres el sitio donde hay discrepancias no entiendes el porque, entonces haz la pregunta especificando los detalles.

Comment: gracias por su colaboracion, realice lo que me dijeron tanto que lo depure como que agrege un print que imprima las monedas que uso y salio lo que correji es:  System.out.println("Ingrese el monto a abonar");
        apagar = sc.nextDouble();
        double pago = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < monedas.length; i++) {
            pago = pago + monedas[i];
            if (pago <= apagar) {
               System.out.println(monedas[i]);
            } else {
               pago = pago-monedas[i];
            }

        }